# Python how to check if variable exist and its length, in one if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

Here's my situation:

```
if var:
    if len(var) == 5:
        do something...
else:
    do the same thing...
```

To avoid repeating the same piece of code, I would like to combine those 2 if conditions, in one. But if var is None, I can't check its length... Any idea? 
I would like something like this:

```
if var and len(var) == 5:
    do something...
```

Comment: What you suggested is fine. `if var and len(var) == 5` will work

Comment: In addition to what everyone already said (i.e. that your suggestion indeed works as you expect) why are you checking for length if you are going to do the same thing anyway? Also note that in general when you have a body of code that you don't want to repeat the tool to use is a function or a method (depending on how much context is needed by the code).

Comment: I shouldn't ask questions at night, hoping to get an answer in the morning... I was sure I tried that and it didn't work...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you try that?  It works:

```
if var and len(var) == 5:
    ....
```

The `and` operator doesn't evaluate the RHS if the LHS is false.  Try this:

```
>>> False and 1/0
False
>>> True and 1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: if var doesn't exist, he wants to do something as well, no?

Comment: @steabert: Add `not` or `else` to your code as you see fit.  I'm not here to write your code, just to answer questions.

Comment: There is one snag here (which might or might not be relevant to @Tickon): This solution does not discriminate between the cases `var == []` and `var is None`. In the former case, `len(var)` can be determined (`== 0`), in the latter it can't. (However, I don't think this is a reason to downvote this answer)

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: But if `var == []`, then `len(var) != 5`, no?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: True. I think it's too early in the morning for boolean algebra :)

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: Thanks for explaining why it works, that's useful.

Answer (score 3):

The code as you've written it in the question executes the statements in two cases:

- `var` evaluates to true and has a length of 5
- `var` evaluates to false (e.g. it's `None` or `False`)

You can combine those into one conditional as follows:

```
if not var or len(var) == 5:
    ...
```

The conditional that some other answers are suggesting, `var and len(var) == 5`, only evaluates to `True` in the first case, not the second. I will say, though, that the two cases you've chosen are kind of an unusual combination. Are you sure you didn't intend to execute the statements only if the variable has a non-false value *and* has a length of 5?

Additionally, as 6502 wrote in a comment, functions are intended for exactly this case, namely making reusable code blocks. So another easy solution would be

```
 def f():
     ....
 if var:
     if var.length == 5:
         f()
 else:
     f()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, exceptions seem to be perfectly fine here.

```
try:
    if len(var) == 5:
        do_something()
except TypeError:
    pass
```

You're saying that `var` can be null, therefore a `TypeError` exception would be thrown. If, however, in fact `var` can be non-existant at all, you should catch for `NameError` exception.

Comment: This is the solution that does exactly what @Tickon is asking for. Only if `var is None` (or a different non-subscriptable type, but that wasn't asked here), the exception will be triggered. And it's more Pythonic for what it's worth.